# How to generate a barcode (code 128) with 44 characters and width equals 7.9 centimeters (223,937 points) in java?

Tags: java, barcode, code128

I can generate barcodes with 300 width,  but no matter java library i use , i can't figure out how to generate one with smaller sises. If i try to resize the barcode it loses its quality and the online scaners don't reead it (https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx).
i already tryed using barcode4j, barbiecue, xzing, keepdynamic and IDAutomation libraries.

The string i want to use is this 22200435041996000168550010000001321731592625

The barcode should be as in the image below inside the rect thas has 7.9 centimeters.
It's a pdf.

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think your problem is your page size. 223937 points is **not** 8 cm. There are 72 points to an inch. 223937 points is 43.2 inches (or 110 cm). 8cm is 3.15 inches or 227 points.

Comment: well at least google says "3,14961 inches to points = 226,77192" and "226,77192 points to cm = 8"

Comment: Aha! Are you in a locale that uses `,` as a decimal point? I spent years working for a newspaper. It is 72 points / inch. Apparently since [the time of Gutenberg's press](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/413/21390). Anyway, 3.15 inches is about 227 points. Points are not fractional.